# MySQL database, multiple foreign keys

Tags: mysql

I'm new to the world of MySQL and I'm having a bit of trouble. Here's the problem:

I have 2 tables called **TEAMS** and **FIXTURES**. Here's the structure I'm trying to create (only showing relevant fields):

TEAMS table:

- team_name (Primary key)

FIXTURES table:

- fixture_id (Primary key)
- home_team (Foreign key)
- away_team (Foreign key)

home_team and away_team **both** get a team name from the same source (team_name).

I've successfully created the relationship with the FIXTURES(**home**_team) and TEAMS(team_name), but I can't get the other relationship working - FIXTURES(**away**_team) and TEAMS(team_name).

I get the "*#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails*" error message. I'm assuming could be because I have 2 foreign keys in the same table referencing the same primary key. Is that correct? If so, how would I fix it?

Hopefully I've explained this ok and that someone can help me, thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means you already have value that doesn't satisfy the constraint, i.e. having no corresponding entry in the `teams` table. So the problem is not with the schema, but with your data. Fix the issue there.

```
SELECT * FROM fixtures LEFT JOIN teams ON (away_team=team_name)
WHERE team_name IS NULL;
```

will fetch you the offending rows.

Comment: It was such a simple solution. I wasn't aware that my incomplete test data would affect me completing the structure. Once I filled out the missing data field everything worked as I wanted. Thank you so much :-)